# How should I handle file descriptor 'dependencies' when using epoll?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, file-descriptor, epoll

I'm writing an HTTP/2 server in C, using epoll. Let's say a client asks for `/index.html` - I need to open a file descriptor pointing to that file and then send it back to the socket whenever I read a chunk of it. So I'd have an event loop that looks something like this:

```
while (true)
    events = epoll_wait()
    for event in events
        if event is on a socket
            handle socket i/o
        else if event is on a disk file
            read as much as possible, and send to associated socket
```

However this poses a problem. If the socket then closes (for whatever reason), the file descriptor for `index.html` will also get closed too. But it's possible that the `index.html` FD will have already been queued for reading (i.e, it's already in `events`, since you closed it between calls to `epoll_wait`), and as such when the for loop gets to processing the FD I'll now be accessing a 'dangling' FD.

If this was a single threaded program I'd try and hack around the issue by looking at file descriptor numbers, but unfortunately I'm running the same epoll loop on multiple threads which means that I can't predict what FD numbers will be in use at a given moment. It's totally possible that by the time the invalid read on the file comes around, another thread will have claimed that FD, so the call to `read` won't explicitly fail but I'll probably get a use after free anyway for trying to send it on a socket that doesn't exist anymore.

What's the best way of dealing with this issue? Maybe I should take an entirely different approach and not have file I/O on the same epoll loop at all.

Comment: Files have no "events" on them as they are _always_ ready. You shouldn't use `epoll` on them. As for your question, if you close the socket, you need to close the file and remove event from the queue (or mark it as "invalid"). If there are multiple threads, then removing it is not an option, but access to it should be synchronized and it should be marked somehow. The absence of socket should be enough actually.

Comment: Good point, totally overlooked that. What about for other types of FDs, say a `timerfd`? The same issue still exists, as far as I can see.

Comment: But do you really need this? If socket is ready to be written to, just write all data from file, if it is not, then don't. For other cases you will need to be more specific. If one fd does not need to be polled, there is no problem. If you need timeouts, then you should probably just have a mutex around `fd`. On timeout it can be closed and set to `-1` (atomic operations can be used too).

Comment: That's true, I suppose. I guess it makes things easier now that I realise that file I/O isn't going to be on the epoll loop. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @Ivan Not sure I understand what you mean by using mutexes. In my design each socket is only ever used on one thread, so I don't need to worry about other threads accessing the socket during a close operation or whatever. But I don't see how a mutex would help, won't that just block?

Comment: If you need one socket (or timefd) to access another one. But this is not easy to do, since you can have both mutexes being locked in reversed order from multiple threads, leading to a deadlock. Splitting even processing in multiple stages can help: read-write stage followed by fd closing stage, for example. This way fds are never unexpectedly closed, but this might be hard to run in multiple threads.

Comment: Sorry to butt in, but if you're using a thread per connection than you're already limiting your server by design. Consider each thread adds the cost for the thread's stack allocation (~2Mb) and context switches (OS scheduler costs). At 10K connections you will hit 20Gb of memory just for thread stacks... seriously, the design is an issue. Consider alternative designs, even if you do require a Mutex, such as a single threaded evented approach or a thread pool with an event queue. I'm [facil.io](http://facil.io)'s author, so I have some experience with this.

Comment: I’m not using a thread per connection, I probably worded it badly. I meant each socket is only ever handled by one out of four worker threads, each running epoll. The main thread simply calls accept and passes the sockets off to the worker threads (this might be a bottleneck, but we’ll see). I do it this way to avoid the thundering herd problem.

Comment: @HexCoder, I'm happy I misunderstood  As for `accept` being a bottle neck, it's a design choice. I believe accepting new connections should be avoided when the server is busy (this allows for better load balancing), so I opted to make the `accept` operation just another event handled by the workers (if they are busy, it will be delayed and it will allow for inter-process load balancing)..

Comment: I'm Assuming you're using some kind of user-land buffer to manage partial `write` calls. why not use the same logic, so when the buffer is empty (it's all sent) the file is read and another frame is pushed to the outgoing buffer...? (if it were facil.io, I guess I would use the buffer deallocation callback schedule a task that reads the file and submits a new packet to be written).

Comment: @Myst Yep, that’s exactly the idea I was having. BTW how do you avoid the issue of multiple worker threads each receiving EPOLLIN events on the server fd before calls to accept? (Thundering herd problem)

Comment: @HexCoder I'm using the One-Shot flag (both on `kqueue` and `epoll`), which means that I don't push the listening socket back to the queue until I'm done accepting (or reading). This resolves the thundering herd, but it does increase the number of system calls, so I'm not sure it was worth the extra effort... but still, I like it better this way, because it will be easier to port the code to completion ports (Windows / Solaris) if I ever get to that. (`EPOLLONESHOT`)